# How to make a autoclicker that makes the user click on random spots of the screen with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a autoclicker chrome browser extension, but how can I simulate a mouse click using javascript? And how can i make the it click on a random spot of the screen? Thanks for helping!

Comment: just random clicking? or targeting a specific element?

Comment: random clicking

Answer (score 2):

Simply by `click()` function.

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').click();
```

If you want a random click use:

```
let els = document.querySelectorAll('body *');
var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * els.length );
els[rand].click();
```

Comment: then, the user needs to input the id of the button first, thats not really wat i want...

Comment: where on the page you want to click?

Comment: no, sorry. it does not work for me...

Comment: You just want a random click on anything in body. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Create a button with an id & onClick function:

```
<button id="clickMe" onclick="clicked()">Click Here</button>
```

Call the click function:

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").click();
```

Add this loop to automate 1000 clicks!

```
for ( let i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
  document.getElementById("clickMe").click();
}
```